# HTTP Request in Python VS. Apache Camel?

Tags: python-3.x, forms, apache-camel, java-11

I'm converting a Python script into Camel.
This script connect to an HMTL that contains a login form, doing a GET request.

It then extract the headers parameters from de response, add them to a POST request adding also a payload containing the credentials and finally submit the request.

```
r = requests.get(self.base_url, proxies=self.proxy, verify=self.verify_ssl)
cookie_string = r.headers.get('set-cookie')
temp_headers = {"Cache-Control": 'no-cache', "cookie": cookie_string}
connection_payload = {'email': self.username, 'password': self.password}
r = requests.post(self.base_url, headers=temp_headers, data=connection_payload, proxies=self.proxy, verify=self.verify_ssl)
```

This code works well.

In the Java version of it, I have tried:

```
public class WebRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    final HttpComponent httpComponent = createHttpComponent();
    final Endpoint loginEndpoint = httpComponent.createEndpoint(WEBAPI_AUTH_URI_LOGIN);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:login")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.POST)
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("email=${body.username}&password=${body.password}"))
        .to(loginEndpoint);
    }

    private HttpComponent createHttpComponent() {
        HttpComponent httpComponent = getCamelContext().getComponent(PROXY_SCHEME, HttpComponent.class);
        httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(sslContextParameters);
        httpComponent.setUseGlobalSslContextParameters(true);
        httpComponent.setProxyAuthScheme(PROXY_SCHEME);
        httpComponent.setProxyAuthHost(PROXY_HOST);
        httpComponent.setProxyAuthPort(PROXY_PORT);
        httpComponent.setCookieManagementDisabled(true);
        return httpComponent;
    }
}
```

The issue isn't with the http component configuration made to use a SSL certificate.
It work well (passing the proxy and getting the response containing the form I try to login),just mentioning it as it is also the endpoint  that I use to issue the POST request.

**The problem**

With the Java code above, the server respond:

```
HTTP operation failed invoking https://a.b.c?user=x@y.z&password=xxxxxx with statusCode: 400
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the way I'm passing the credentials:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("email=${body.username}&password=${body.password}"))
```

Tried many variations of it, inluding for e.g. using "RAW(password)" without success.

**Question**

How can be rewrite in Camel the Python query above, in particular the `connection_payload` parameter part ?

Answer (score 0):

You're sure the password and username should be stored in the body? A property or header seems like a better place for this. Because right now you will also be sending this data in the body of your request.

Also in your example you are using two different fields: user and email. This is likely your main problem.

`.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple("user=${header.username}&password=${header.password}"))`

You could also use `.toD` to [dynamically set the endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/toD-eip.html) if you will be using different usernames and passwords:

`.toD("http:myloginserver:8080/login?user=${header.username}&password=${header.password}")`

Comment: HI. It isn't stored in the body, but appended to the url as query parameters. As for toD, I also tried that without success, unfortunately

Comment: Did you see my comment about the two different field names? You send an `email` field, but the server response is asking for a `user`.

Comment: Yes. But in this case, it's normal: the bean containing the cedentials have a "username" field, while the server use the email fied. The Python is doing the same switch and the Python script work